# What are the caveats of using source versus parse & eval?

Tags: r, eval

### Short version

Can I replace

```
source(filename, local = TRUE, encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

with

```
eval(parse(filename, encoding = 'UTF-8'))
```

without any risk of breakage, to make UTF-8 source files work on Windows?

### Long version

I am currently loading specific source files via

```
source(filename, local = TRUE, encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

However, it is well known that [this does not work on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5031630/1968), full stop.

As a workaround, [Joe Cheng suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5588488/1968) using instead

```
eval(parse(filename, encoding = 'UTF-8'))
```

This seems to work quite well<sup>1</sup> but even after consulting the source code of `source`, I don’t understand how they differ in one crucial detail:

Both `source` and `sys.source` do **not** simply `parse` and then `eval` the file content. Instead, they parse the file content and then *iterate manually* over the parsed expressions, and `eval` them one by one. I do not understand why this would be necessary in `sys.source` (`source` at least uses it to show verbose diagnostics, if so instructed; but `sys.source` does [nothing of the kind](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/38b83c4aee0b981363ffe922f11fe10350de0f96/src/library/base/R/source.R#L261)):

```
for (i in seq_along(exprs)) eval(exprs[i], envir)
```

**What is the purpose of `eval`ing statements separately?** And why is it iterating over indices instead directly over the sub-expressions? What other caveats are there?

<sub>To clarify: I am *not* concerned about the additional parameters of `source` and `parse`, some of which may be set via options.</sub>

---

<sup>1</sup> The reason that `source` is tripped up by the encoding but `parse` isn’t boils down to the fact that `source` attempts to convert the input text. `parse` does no such thing, it reads the file’s byte content as-is and simply marks its `Encoding` as `UTF-8` in memory.

Comment: Why are you doing any of those? Put your code in packages.

Comment: @Spacedman Why do these commands even exist then? (For a more specific reason: because I’m working on an [alternative package system](https://github.com/klmr/modules).)

Comment: @Spacedman [You know](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789036/namespaces-without-packages#comment22478647_15789538) he doesn't want to, so why [keep poking](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2014-April/068926.html) that bear (especially on an only tangentially related question such as this)?!

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Ah yes. I’ve done that.

Comment: Ah. Still working on that module system. Fairy Nuff.

Comment: So is this question purely "What's the difference between `eval(exprs)` and `for(ex in exprs)eval(ex)` and `for(i in seq_along(exprs))eval(exprs[i])`?"? (give or take an `envir` here and there) Its a bit messy as it stands. I mean, all the UTF stuff is irrelevant, and your real question comes in half way through.

Comment: @Spacedman Not purely, since the sources of `source` and `parse` are long and obscure and I might have missed another important difference – notably with the involvement of `srcfilecopy`, which I do not entirely understand. And providing context is generally seen as crucial on Stack Overflow, in order to determine whether the OP has fallen prey to an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). My *actual* question is therefore the one in the title, and explained by the first few paragraphs.

Comment: So just to clarify a bit more: Joe Cheng's `eval(parse(...))` workaround is so far working just fine, but you're wanting to know if there are any consequential differences that might, at some point, bite, right? And you're naturally a bit uneasy, since you're not fully following what the source code does (and where you are following it, you're not always understanding its rationale)... Is your ultimate (but maybe too-vague-for-SO) question really, "can somebody confirm that `eval(parse(...))` is an everywhere reliable replacement for `source(...)`"?

Comment: @Josh Yes. All my tests pass but they are of course not exhaustive and I cannot test easily on Windows. Furthermore, I intended to reference this discussion in a source code comment as an explanation.

Comment: The [**evaluate**](http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/web/packages/evaluate/index.html) package authors (Yihui, Hadley, and Barret Schloerke) might have some interesting insight into your question. **evaluate** underlies **knitr**'s statement-by-statement evaluation of R code, and it works by parsing and then "manually" iterating over parsed expressions, evaluating each in turn. If anybody would know about the potential "gotcha"s of doing or not doing that, I'd think they might be the ones.

Comment: @Autar The “source” tag in this instance referred to a specific technique (actually, the `source` function) — not the generic “source code”. I’m pretty sure that’s not meant by the ban of the “source” tag. That said, it’s maybe a little too specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a full answer as it primarily addresses the `seq_along` part of the question, but too lengthy to include as comments.

One key difference between the `seq_along` followed by `[` vs just using `for i in x` approach (which I believe is be similar to `seq_along` followed by `[[` instead of `[`) is that the former preserves the expression.  Here is an example to illustrate the difference:

```
> txt <- "x <- 1 + 1
+ # abnormal expression
+   2 *
+     3
+ "
> x <- parse(text=txt, keep.source=TRUE)
> 
> for(i in x) print(i)
x <- 1 + 1
2 * 3
> for(i in seq_along(x)) print(x[i])
expression(x <- 1 + 1)
expression(2 *
    3)
```

Alternatively:

```
> attributes(x[[2]])
NULL
> attributes(x[2])
$srcref
$srcref[[1]]
2 *
    3
```

Whether this has any practical impact when comparing to `eval(parse(..., keep.source=T))`, I can only say that it could, but can't imagine a situation where it does.

Note that subsetting expression separately also leads to the `srcref` business getting subset, which could conceivably be useful (...maybe?).