# Can't source skript with rare characters in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Following the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495598/replace-accented-characters-in-r-with-non-accented-counterpart-utf-8-encoding) I'm trying to implement a script that replaces accented characters. Executing my code from console works fine, however when I execute this code:

```
x <- list('ÿ'='y')
```

from a RStudio script R returns following error:

> source('~/R/DrivingDataAnalysis/R/WebScraper/VoltstatsScraper.R', encoding = 'UTF-8')
>   Error in source("~/TestScript.R",  : 
>     ~/TestScript.R:1:6: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING
>   1: list('
>            ^

for other accented characters like in the link R parses the script. How can I make this work in a script? I'm using R 3.3.1 and RStudio 0.99.896 on Windows 7.

Comment: I can't replicate this problem on RStudio 0.99.1266 (preview). Looks like UTF-8 encoding was introduced in 0.99.903 (see https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding) so you may just need to update your version of RStudio

Comment: Thanks for your help. Updating RStudio to 0.99.903 did resolve the issue when setting the encoding to: ISO-8859-1. However for the ordinary UTF-8 encoding the problem remains. Have you tried to set you encoding  to "UTF-8" to reproduce the error? Also setting the encoding i.e. to WINDOWS-1252 generates this error.

Comment: Non-ASCII characters + R + Windows == you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: yep pretty much looks like it :-). As this one is the only character of a larger list it is not the end of the world thanks anyways

Comment: Although Kevin is right, you generally should set your encoding to UTF-8, and there’s pretty much never a reason to use a legacy encoding such as Windows-foo/ISO-bar. To work around R bugs with Unicode on Windows, use [`eval(parse(…, encoding = 'UTF-8')` instead of `source(…)`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24454559/1968).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer because I think it will fix your problem:

- Ensure that your script is encoded in `UTF-8`. [Everything else is madness.](http://utf8everywhere.org/)<sup>1</sup>
- Instead of using `source`, which fundamentally doesn’t work, use

  ```
  eval(parse('your/file.r', encoding = 'UTF-8'))
  ```

  [This works as a substitute for `source`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24454559/1968) As the linked answer explains, the reason is that `source` tries (and fails) to convert the UTF-8-encoded characters, whereas `parse` doesn’t perform any transformation; instead, it loads the string verbatim from the file and simply marks it as UTF-8 encoded.

Unfortunately this you’ll have to do this manually, assuming that RStudio’s “source” button uses `source` rather than the above workaround internally.

---

<sup>1</sup> Other Unicode transformations might make sense but are — as far as I know — not at all supported by R.