# R's equivalent to Python's importing mechanism

Tags: python, r, import

In Python, suppose we have:

```
lib.py:
def myFunction():
  ...

main.py:
  import lib
  lib.myFunction()
```

so that `myFunction` is in module `lib` and is not going to pollute the global environment.

However, in R, to use `myFunction`:

```
lib.R:
myFunction <- function(...) {...}

main.R:
source("lib.R")
myFunction()
```

so that `myFunction` is in the global environment. If `lib.R` has other functions, all of them will be poured into the global environment, which is highly undesirable.

**My question** is: Is there a way in R to "import" a user-defined function in other files without polluting the global environment?

I guess writing a R package might alleviate the problem, but in my case, it is not worth it to write a full-fledged package.

Comment: You can use `sys.source()` to load functions into an environment other than the global one, but they won't be very fun to execute. You're better off writing a package. Not sure what makes you think it's not worth it if that's exactly the behavior you are after.

Comment: I've never used it, but you could maybe look at the modules packages by @klmr

Comment: See here for a discussion about it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15789036/324364

Comment: Two options: assign to a specific environment or make a package.

Answer (score 0):

If you import two libraries with same function name, you can use `libraryname::function(...)`.

This won't solve your problem, but will ensure you're using the correct function from the correct library.