# Registering S4 equivalents of R6 classes while preserving inheritance

Tags: r, methods, namespaces, r-s4, r6

### Actual question

How can I turn a bunch of R6 classes that inherit from each other into S4 classes while preserving the inheritance structure when all classes need to live in a package's namespace (as opposed to in `GlobalEnv`)?

### Details

Everything works fine in cases where the R6 classes have been defined in `.GlobalEnv` (as when sourcing with `source()`) and `setOldClass()` is also called with `where = .GlobalEnv`.

But I cannot get it to work when the R6 classes have been defined inside a package's namespace (as when calling `devtools::load_all()`):

Defining the R6 classes in `.GlobalEnv`:

```
Object <- R6Class("Object", portable = TRUE, public = list(
  foo = function() "foo")
)
Api <- R6Class("Api", inherit = Object, portable = TRUE,
  public = list(bar = function() "bar")
)
Module <- R6Class("Module", inherit = Api, portable = TRUE,
  public = list(fooBar = function() "fooBar")
```

Calling `setOldClass()` with `where = .GlobalEnv` (the default for `where`):

```
setOldClass(c("Object", "R6"))
setOldClass(c("Api", "Object"))
setOldClass(c("Module", "Api"))
```

When the R6 classes are defined inside a package's namespace (as when "sourcing" with `devtools::load_all()` instead of `source()`), I assumed that I need to account for that by providing an explicit `where`:

```
where <- if ("package:r6.s4" %in% search()) {
  as.environment("package:r6.s4")
} else {
  .GlobalEnv
}
try(setOldClass(c("Object", "R6"), where = where))
try(setOldClass(c("Api", "Object"), where = where))
try(setOldClass(c("Module", "Api"), where = where))
```

However, that leaves me with the following error:

> Error in setOldClass(c("Module", "Api"), where = where) : 
>     inconsistent old-style class information for “Module”; the class is defined but does not extend “Api” and is not valid as the data part

---

### Facilitating reproducability

I tried to make this issue as easily reproducible as possible, so you'll find the `r6.s4` package at my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/rappster/r6.s4/blob/master/R/classes.r)

**Note again that you have to run `devtools::load_all()` (or hit `CRTL + SHFT + L` in RStudio) in order to reproduce the error**.

Also, this [unit test](https://github.com/rappster/r6.s4/blob/master/tests/testthat/test-S4.r) might help in figuring out what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it figured out.

### Lessons learned

1. The reason `setOldClass(c("Module", "Api"))` fails is due to the fact that package `Rcpp` has a class with identical name defined.

   ```
   require("R6")
   > getClass("Module")
   Class "Module" [package "Rcpp"]

   Slots:

     Name:       .xData
   Class: environment

   Extends: 
     Class ".environment", directly
   Class "environment", by class ".environment", distance 2, with explicit coerce
   Class "refObject", by class ".environment", distance 3, with explicit coerce
   ```
2. The best place to call `setOldClass()` seems to be inside `.onAttach()` as at this stage the package has been fully loaded and thus a namespace environment exists that the `where` argument can point to.

   ```
   .onAttach <- function(libname, pkgname) {
     where <- as.environment("package:r6.s4")
     clss <- list(
       c("Object", "R6"),
       c("Api", "Object"),
       c("Module2", "Api")
     )
     sapply(clss, function(cls) {
       try(setOldClass(cls, where = where))
     })
   }
   ```
3. Inside `.onAttach()`, you need to be carful with not "overloading" classes that have been set by `setOldClass()` on previous package loads. That's why something along the lines of this might make sense:

   ```
    .onAttach <- function(libname, pkgname) {
     where <- as.environment("package:r6.s4")
     clss <- list(
       c("Object", "R6"),
       c("Api", "Object"),
       c("Module2", "Api")
     )
     sapply(clss, function(cls) {
       idx <- sapply(cls, isClass)
       try(sapply(cls[idx], removeClass, where = where))
       try(setOldClass(cls, where = where))
     })      
   }
   ```
4. I like the approach of `R6` relying on actual **generator objects** instead of mere class names **a lot** as it empowers you to use `::` and thus keep classes as organized as all of your other package components. But that paradigm unfortunately seems to be lost when registering S4 equivalents for them via `setOldClass()`. That kind of takes me back to my old complaint about the increasing risk of [name clashes for classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947159/writing-robust-r-code-namespaces-masking-and-using-the-operator) - `*sigh*`.

For those of you interested in the details of my trial-and-error process: I've tried to turn the package into sort of a self-reference. Check files [R/classes.r](https://github.com/rappster/r6.s4/blob/master/R/classes.r), [tests/testthat/test-S4.r](https://github.com/rappster/r6.s4/blob/master/tests/testthat/test-S4.r) as well as some prototype code on how to check for and handle name clashes [R/name_clashes.r](https://github.com/rappster/r6.s4/blob/master/R/name_clashes.r).

Comment: I have a similar situation. But in my package I wrote some methods for the classes defined in the package (i.e. `Api` and `Module2` in your example), for a generic S4 function defined in some other package (e.g. `sp::coordinates`) using something like: `setMethod('coordinates', signature = 'Api') { ... }`. 
This results in an error when loading the package, because the class `Api` is not registered at the time where `R` parses the new method.