# R package scope and masking

Tags: r, scope, namespaces, package

I think this is a simple question, and the answer is probably somewhere in either Hadley's book or the official R documentation, or in the answers to [Writing robust R code: namespaces, masking and using the `::` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10947159/2954547), but I haven't come across it yet (or don't remember reading about it).

Let's say I want to write a package that contains the function:

```
sort_by_column <- function(x, j) {
  j_ord <- order(x[, j])
  x[j_ord, ]
}
```

If I define this function in the global environment and I pass in a value for `x` that is a `data.table`, it will silently fail because `[` will dispatch to `[.data.table` instead of `[.data.frame`:

```
library(data.table)
sort_by_column(iris, 3)
sort_by_column(data.table(iris), 3)
```

My gut tells me that `[.data.table` won't even be available to my package unless I explicitly `import` it, in which case this problem can't occur in a package the way it can occur in the global environment. Is that true? If not, how can I handle this kind of masking?

edit 2: **Function `sort_by_column` is defined in package `A`. Another package, `B` was loaded before package `A` but is not explictly imported by `A`. Do calls from functions defined in `A` search in package `B`?**

edit: To clarify, I want to define a function *inside a package* in such a way that it "ignores" other packages the user might have loaded, in order to avoid function naming conflicts like the one demonstrated above. Is this ignoring behavior automatic, or do I need to do something in particular?

Comment: If your function in the package or the global or both?

Comment: @csgillespie it's in the package. I was just using the global scope to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: `[` being generic, it will look at the class of the object. If it's a data.table, it will try to call a `[.data.table`. If that's what you want to happen, you should import it explicitly in DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE. If you haven't done so, `[` will search for a `[.data.table` method on the user's search path, in which case unpredictable results may occur.  If the search path doesn't have any corresponding `data.table` method, it will default to the `data.frame` one (since `data.table` inherits from `data.frame`)

Comment: @baptiste I want that to _not_ happen. See my edit in bold

Comment: then use DWin's answer below, bypassing the class check with `[.data.frame`. You may want to rename it for clarity, e.g. `get_col <- function(x, j) base::"[.data.frame"(x, TRUE, j)`. Alternatively, use `as.data.frame` before anything in your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to specify a particular method for "[" then you should be able to use:

```
 `[.data.frame`(x, TRUE, j)
```

Or test for data.tables using `inherits` and trap that as an edge case?