# R: DESCRIPTION-file fails to import the dependencies

Tags: r, cran, roxygen2

still having some problems with creating R-package. I'm trying to organize some import dependencies to my package and this seems to go wrong.

I setup my DESCRIPTION-file as shown below and when i call the first method i get an error. It seems like the workspace still missing the import which leeds to my 
first question:

```
Package: Concentration
Type: Package
Title: A package for Concentration
Version: 1.0
Date: 2015-08-10
Author: I'm the author
Maintainer: I'm the maintainer
Description: This package implements XXXXX
Depends: R (>= 0.98.1103)
Imports:
    XLConnect,
    ggplot2,
    scales
License: HAW-Ostfalia / Brunschwig
```

1- how do i properly organize import with CRAN/Roxygen

2- I've got some functions in my package which depend on others in the same package. How can I make sure R-CMD automatically recognizes/calls them in the runtime?

Hier ist the error i get:

```
> library(Concentration)
> xy <- extract.xy("1 AR Procymidone.xlsx")
Error in extract.xy("1 AR Procymidone.xlsx") : 
  konnte Funktion "loadWorkbook" nicht finden
```

Which means much like the method "extract.xy" can't find "loadWorkbook". Has anybody an idea how it works? Thanks.

Comment: what is in your namespace

Comment: what do u mean bout that? In my workspace i don't have nothing yet. Concentration is my package's name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136366/best-practices-for-roxygen-imports-depends

Comment: Are you sure about this line: `Depends: R (>= 0.98.1103)`? That looks like an RStudio / RStudio Server version number rather than an R version number...

Comment: i use a Mac-version... I guess, it's not the same as windows? Don't know...

Comment: @Lycone it is not a matter for of OS, but the R. Looks like the version you used is RStudio version, which is not R, it is an IDE for R.