# How to avoid namespace ambiguity for user defined functions

Tags: r

Avoiding potential unambiguity from namespace collisions for functions that come from libraries can be achieved by prepending the package name to the function call (e.g. `dplyr::left_join`, `plyr::left_join` etc), as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947159/writing-robust-r-code-namespaces-masking-and-using-the-operator)

How can this unambiguity be achieved for a user defined function? (i.e. one that **did not** come from a library/package). Obviously you cannot prepend the package name to a function if the function did not come from a package

### Example

```
library(dplyr)
left_join <- function(x, y) { x + y }

dplyr::left_join(x,y) # Unambiguously calls left_join from dplyr
left_join(x, y) # Not clear whether from dplyr or user defined
```

How can user defined functions be called unambiguously?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dummy function I have written. I have not rigorously tested it so it might break:

```
import_from_global<-function(what,...){
  func<-get(what,envir=.GlobalEnv) 
  do.call(func,list(...))
}
```

Test:

```
select<-function(){
  cat("using namespace .GlobalEnv\n") 
  print("Does nothing")
}
import_from_global("select")
```

Result:

```
using namespace .GlobalEnv
[1] "Does nothing"
```